# VBA, object not found 424 error - how to debug?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, error-handling

I'm using VBA on Excel 2010 and Im getting the dreaded 424 error. But the debugger does not point to anything to assist with resolution. Is there a good practice for being able to narrow down the issue? I've checked the spelling, all the tables are on the correct sheet and the Columns as named are there.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may be able to offer.

```
Sub Finding_Zone()

Dim Data_Table As ListObject
Dim Freq_Table As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim Zone_Value As Long

Set Data_Table = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")
Set Freq_Table = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3")

For i = 1 To Range(Data_Table).Rows.Count
    Zone_Value = data.Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Data_Table.ListColumns("Zone").Index)


For x = 1 To Len(Zone_Value)

    Set Result = Freq_Table.ListColumns("Summary Code").DataBodyRange.Find(Zone_Value)

    If Result Is Nothing Then

        Zone_Value = Left(Zone_Value, Len(Zone_Value) - 1)

    Else
        Data_Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Data_Table.ListColumns("Modified Zone").Index) = Zone_Value
        End If

Next x

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: When stepping through with F8 does it not fail on a particular line?

Comment: What is `data.Table` in `Zone_Value = data.Table.DataBodyRange...`? Your `ListObject` is `Data_Table`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to encase Data_Table inside of range (which doesn't have a specified parent) as opposed to using the   Data_Table.Range.Rows.Count

Comment: When I debug it highlights Sub Finding_Zone()

Comment: @BigBen - now changed. Thanks.

Comment: @QHarr - I changed it to For i = 1 To Data_Table.Rows.Count but now it says method or data member not found

Comment: @AnthonyDixon pay attention to intellisense. when you type that dot after `Data_Table.`, you get a dropdown - in that dropdown is every member that exists on the public interface of your `ListObject`; `Rows` isn't a member, but you'll find `ListRows` in that dropdown.

Comment: As per ^^ comment, What I wrote was Data_Table.Range.Rows.Count  but you may actually want only to loop through the dataBodyRange rows.

Comment: Another problem: `Len` used on a `Long` will return the number of bytes (4), not the number of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, `Option Explicit` would have caught the `data.Table` typo, which causes the `Object Not Found` error. However, these additional points should help you refine the code.

---

- `Len(Zone_Value)` does not return the number of digits in your zone number, but rather will always return **4** - the number of bytes used (storage size of a `Long`). See [MSDN - Data Type Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary) for more detail. `For x = 1 To Len(Zone_Value)` will loop 4 times, and `Len(Zone_Value) - 1` will equal 3, no matter how many digits `Zone_Value` has. So maybe use `Cstr` to cast `Zone_Value` to a `String` and then check its length.

Consider this sample code showing the length of `1` when assigned to `Double`, `Long`, `Integer` and `String` variables.

```
Sub TestLength()
    Dim a As Double, b As Long, c As Integer, d As String

    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = 1
    d = "1"

    Debug.Print "Length of a: " & Len(a)
    Debug.Print "Length of b: " & Len(b)
    Debug.Print "Length of c: " & Len(c)
    Debug.Print "Length of d: " & Len(d)
End Sub
```

The output is:

> ```
> Length of a: 8
> Length of b: 4
> Length of c: 2
> Length of d: 1
> ```

**Another thought:**

- `Zone_Value = data.Table.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, Data_Table.ListColumns("Zone").Index)`. It might be simpler and more understandable to add a `ListColumn` variable, instead of referencing the `Index` multiple times.

`Dim Zone_Column As ListColumn: Set Zone_Column = Data_Table.ListColumns("Zone")`

---

Your revised code, implementing both suggestions, might look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Finding_Zone()
    Dim Data_Table As ListObject: Set Data_Table = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")
    Dim Freq_Table As ListObject: Set Freq_Table = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3")

    Dim Zone_Column As ListColumn: Set Zone_Column = Data_Table.ListColumns("Zone")
    Dim Summary_Column As ListColumn: Set Summary_Column = Freq_Table.ListColumns("Summary Code")
    Dim Mod_Zone_Column As ListColumn: Set Mod_Zone_Column = Data_Table.ListColumns("Modified Zone")

    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim Zone_Value As Long
    Dim Result As Range
    Dim tmpStr As String

    With Zone_Column.DataBodyRange
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Zone_Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            tmpStr = CStr(Zone_Value)

            For x = 1 To Len(tmpStr)
                Set Result = Summary_Column.DataBodyRange.Find(Zone_Value)

                If Result Is Nothing Then
                    If Len(CStr(Zone_Value)) > 1 Then
                        Zone_Value = CLng(Left(CStr(Zone_Value), Len(CStr(Zone_Value)) - 1))
                    End If
                Else
                    Mod_Zone_Column.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1) = Zone_Value
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next x
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good catch with `Len` there, +1!

Answer (score 1):

`Option Explicit` must be unspecified, [Big Ben saw the typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879583/vba-object-not-found-424-error-how-to-debug#comment90710855_51879583):

> What is `data.Table` in `Zone_Value = data.Table.DataBodyRange...`? Your `ListObject` is `Data_Table`. – BigBen

Should have been `Data_Table`.

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of <s>the module</s> *every single module you ever add code to in VBA*.

Then the code will refuse to compile, because variable `data` isn't declared (the option *forces* you to declare every variable).

As a result, the expression `data.Table.DataBodyRange` is, at run-time, evaluated as a *member call* looking for the `Table` member on an object named `data`, which was declared on-the-fly by VBA (because of the missing `Option Explicit`) as an implicit `Variant` with a value of `Empty`, which is... *not an object*.

Hence, *object required*, because you can't make a *member call* on a *not-an-object*.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) would have told you about the missing `Option Explicit`, the fact that `data` is not declared and never assigned, and used without being assigned. Could also help you make your [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) more consistent ;-)

*Disclaimer: I manage that open-source project*